# LINQ query on object with unknown class

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, reflection, .net-3.5

I have an array of unknown (to the current method) class objects. I do know that each class has a property called "Number".
I am trying to write a LINQ query where I am looking for the object with the next Number in sequence. AKA, I'm at Number 8, use a LINQ query to find the object where Number=9.

Anyone got a suggestion?

Also, I use reflection often so don't worry about avoiding it.

Comment: How do you know that each object has a Number property?  Are they anonymous classes?  Are they of a known type that you can cast to?  Are they all of the same type?

Comment: They could be of ANY class type. I do know though that they all have a Number property though as I have designed them this way.

Comment: If you designed all your classes to have a Number property that means something, but did not capture that meaning in an interface, then you might want to consider changing your design. Your question is best answered with "all the classes with a Number property implement a common interface because you designed them that way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as you indicated elsewhere that you designed all the classes then you could put that number property in an in interface and have all the classes implement that interface. Then, in the linq query, use the interface.

Comment: Forgot about interfaces... Will look into it. Might be possible. I'll still accept other peoples ideas in the mean time.

Comment: @phoog, you beat me. I have posted similar solution :)

Comment: I've got a side issue, one of my classes has a property with a slightly different name. How do I point the interfaces "Number" property to the "Index" Property of this particular class?

Comment: Give the class in question a number property that just returns the index property. I would probably make the new property an explicit implementation.

Comment: @Craig, you can use Explicit Interface Implementation by saying something like `class MyClass : IHasNumber { int IHasNumber.Number { get { return SomeOtherProperty; } } }`. This will make the class implement IHasNumber but will only show that property when you look at it as an IHasNumber. Also, consider asking this in a separate questions so that people can answer outside of comments :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create an interface - INumber with a property Number. Each of the objects that you are having in the array can implemen this interface.

That way, you will have an array of known type INumber. This way your query will be easy to debug and maintain.

Comment: phoog beat me. He has posted similar solution :).

Answer (score 3):

If the objects all inherit from a known interface then you can cast them, e.g.

```
var next = items.Cast<IHasNumber>.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Number == index + 1);
```

If they don't, then you can use `dynamic`, e.g.

```
var next = items.Cast<dynamic>.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Number == index + 1);
```

If you have control of the types, then I would make them implement an interface so that you can use the first method, which should be significantly faster than the second. In that case, your collection will probably be `IEnumerable<IHasNumber>` to start with and you won't even have to cast.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly do not have a common type that you can reduce to and for some reason cannot introduce such a type, then you may be able to use the dynamic keyword.  I don't have access to a compiler at the moment, but can your method accept a collection of dynamic objects and query them?

For example:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> collection = ...;
var numbers = from x in collection
              select x.Number;
```

Comment: We have only just made the move up to .NET 3.5 and are not able to move onto the .NET 4 Framework due to purchasing Visual Studio Licences and the increased Framework size of v4

Comment: @Craig: What is your problem with Framework size? Come on!! It's 2011 now, nobody should care about additional 12 mb

Comment: That is a side-point. The main issue is we only just recently purchased a number of Visual Studio 2008's.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid performance issues you can use the following method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object[] objs = GetInitialData();

    var accessor = GetGetterHelper<int>(objs[0].GetType(), "Number");

    var res = from a in objs where accessor(a) == 7 select a;

}

static Func<object, T> GetGetterHelper<T>(Type type, string methodName)
{
    var methodInfo = type.GetProperty(methodName).GetGetMethod();

    return x => (T)methodInfo.Invoke(x, new object[] {});
}
```